# Solution set for $\lfloor x\rfloor\{x\}=1$

Tags: functions, relations

What is the solution set for $\lfloor x\rfloor\{x\}=1$ , where $\{x\}$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ are respectively fractional part and greatest integer function of $x$.

P.S.: the answer is $\{m+1/m:m\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}\}$. Please explain me the procedure and logic behind these kind of problems .

Answer (score 6):

Suppose
$[x]\{x\}=1
$.
$x$ can not be an integer,
or else
$\{x\}=0$.

Also,
$x>0$
or else
$[x] < 0$
and
$\{x\} > 0$.

Therefore,
let
$[x] = a$
and
$\{x\} = b$,
where $0 < b < 1$.

Then
$ab = 1$,
so
$b = \dfrac1{a}$,
so
$x
= a+b
=a+\dfrac1{a}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that no matter what number is $x$ we have that $\lfloor x\rfloor\in\Bbb Z$. Equating then $\{x\}\in\{1/z:z\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}\}$, and notice that we can write

$$\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$$

Then we can write the equation system

$$x-\lfloor x\rfloor=\frac1z\quad\text{ and }\quad\lfloor x\rfloor=z$$

then we get that

$$z=x-\frac1z\quad\to\quad x=z+\frac1z,\quad\text{ with }z\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$$

P.S.: the definition of the function $\{x\}$ for negative numbers is conflictive, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part), I was using the simpler one.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lfloor x\rfloor\{x\}=1$$

$\lfloor x\rfloor\not =0$. Let $\lfloor x\rfloor=k, k\in Z$. Then 
$$\{x\}=\frac1k$$
$0\le\{x\}<1 \Rightarrow k>0$
T
Then $$x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}=k+\frac1k, k\in \mathbb N$$